# Sys.setlocale line has to be run alone in order to work

Tags: r, shiny, locale

I have a Shiny app and the csv I am using contains Greek characters. In order to work I have to run this line: `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")`.

The problem is this line has to be run alone to get passed. Instead of run as a whole and it's like it isn't being run at all (this line). If I run this line alone then only gets passed and then the app can run with the Greek being shown correctly. I want to make it run altogether when I press 'Reload app' and work as intended.

Comment: Try putting this line inside your `server()` in shiny.

Comment: Didn't work. I put it first after `server = function(input, output, session) {` part. Is this what you suggested?